# Do modern floating point implementations handle exact units (like money) well?

Tags: language-agnostic, floating-point

I am being specific about handling large number of money values. Each value is precise only upto **2 decimal places**. But the values will be passed around by a database and one or more web frameworks and there will be arithemetic operations.

Should I insist on decimal datatypes for numbers that need only 2 places of precision? Or are modern floating point implementations robust and standardized to avoid it?

Comment: Current versions of databases and programming languages. I learned college in C (C++ and java).

Comment: http://www.panix.com/~arnow/brooklyn_college/diatribe.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hell no, absolutely, and the issues are orthogonal, in that order. :-)

Floating point numbers, especially in binary, are  **never** the right choice for fixed-point quantities, least of all those that expect precise fractions, like money values.  First of all, they don't express all values of cents (or whatever fractional component) accurately, just like fixed-length decimal numbers can't express `1/3` correctly.  Secondly, adding or subtracting small and very large floating point numbers doesn't always produce the result you expect, because of differences in "significance".

Decimal numbers are the way to go for currency calculations.  If you absolutely must use binary numbers, use **scaled fixed-point** binary numbers - for example, compute everything in 1/100ths of your currency unit, and use binary integers to do it.

Lastly, this has nothing to do with "robustness" or "standardization" - it's got everything to do with picking a datatype that matches your data.

Answer (score 1):

No, they are not precise enough. See [the floating point guide](http://floating-point-gui.de/) for details.